# Word2Vec.load giving UnpicklingError: could not find MARK and can't resave?

Tags: python, word2vec

I am trying to load my pretrained Word2Vec model. Up until yesterday, it was working fine. Now, I am getting the error `UnpicklingError: could not find MARK`. I saw a similar post and the person just said to resave the model. That is not an option for me.

My code:

```
base_model = Word2Vec.load("sample.model", mmap='r')
```

This is the full error I'm getting

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/Documents/Docs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py:975, in Word2Vec.load(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    974 try:
--> 975     return super(Word2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
    976 except AttributeError:

File ~/Documents/Docs//lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py:629, in BaseWordEmbeddingsModel.load(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    627 @classmethod
    628 def load(cls, *args, **kwargs):
--> 629     model = super(BaseWordEmbeddingsModel, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
    630     if model.negative and hasattr(model.wv, 'index2word'):

File ~/Documents/Docs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py:278, in BaseAny2VecModel.load(cls, fname_or_handle, **kwargs)
    276 @classmethod
    277 def load(cls, fname_or_handle, **kwargs):
--> 278     return super(BaseAny2VecModel, cls).load(fname_or_handle, **kwargs)

File ~/Documents/Docs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/utils.py:426, in SaveLoad.load(cls, fname, mmap)
    425 obj = unpickle(fname)
--> 426 obj._load_specials(fname, mmap, compress, subname)
    427 logger.info("loaded %s", fname)

File ~/Documents/Docs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/utils.py:491, in SaveLoad._load_specials(self, fname, mmap, compress, subname)
    490 logger.info("setting ignored attribute %s to None", attrib)
--> 491 setattr(self, attrib, None)

File ~/Documents/Docs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/utils.py:1398, in deprecated.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.new_func1(*args, **kwargs)
   1393 warnings.warn(
   1394     fmt.format(name=func.__name__, reason=reason),
   1395     category=DeprecationWarning,
   1396     stacklevel=2
   1397 )
-> 1398 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/Documents/Docs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py:450, in BaseWordEmbeddingsModel.cum_table(self, value)
    447 @cum_table.setter
    448 @deprecated("Attribute will be removed in 4.0.0, use self.vocabulary.cum_table instead")
    449 def cum_table(self, value):
--> 450     self.vocabulary.cum_table = value

AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'vocabulary'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [19], in <cell line: 6>()
      3 old_messages = old_messages[['trigramed_tokenized', 'dup_id']].drop_duplicates()
      5 distance = pd.read_csv('distances.csv')
----> 6 base_model = Word2Vec.load("sample.model", mmap='r')
      8 #checking if messages are string
      9 if type(new_message_feats.trigramed_tokenized[0]) == str:

File ~/Documents/Docs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py:979, in Word2Vec.load(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    977 logger.info('Model saved using code from earlier Gensim Version. Re-loading old model in a compatible way.')
    978 from gensim.models.deprecated.word2vec import load_old_word2vec
--> 979 return load_old_word2vec(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/Documents/Docs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/models/deprecated/word2vec.py:153, in load_old_word2vec(*args, **kwargs)
    152 def load_old_word2vec(*args, **kwargs):
--> 153     old_model = Word2Vec.load(*args, **kwargs)
    154     params = {
    155         'size': old_model.vector_size,
    156         'alpha': old_model.alpha,
   (...)
    173         'compute_loss': old_model.__dict__.get('compute_loss', None)
    174     }
    175     new_model = NewWord2Vec(**params)

File ~/Documents/Docs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/models/deprecated/word2vec.py:1616, in Word2Vec.load(cls, *args, **kwargs)
   1614 @classmethod
   1615 def load(cls, *args, **kwargs):
-> 1616     model = super(Word2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
   1617     # update older models
   1618     if hasattr(model, 'table'):

File ~/Documents/Docs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/models/deprecated/old_saveload.py:87, in SaveLoad.load(cls, fname, mmap)
     83 logger.info("loading %s object from %s", cls.__name__, fname)
     85 compress, subname = SaveLoad._adapt_by_suffix(fname)
---> 87 obj = unpickle(fname)
     88 obj._load_specials(fname, mmap, compress, subname)
     89 logger.info("loaded %s", fname)

File ~/Documents/Docs/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/models/deprecated/old_saveload.py:380, in unpickle(fname)
    377 file_bytes = file_bytes.replace(
    378     b'gensim.models.wrappers.fasttext', b'gensim.models.deprecated.fasttext_wrapper')
    379 if sys.version_info > (3, 0):
--> 380     return _pickle.loads(file_bytes, encoding='latin1')
    381 else:
    382     return _pickle.loads(file_bytes)

UnpicklingError: could not find MARK
```

My assumption is that a newer version of gensim got installed when installing another package. I tried uninstalling gensim and the installing gensim==3.4.0. However, this did not help and I am still getting the error. I'm not sure what I can do to use my model

Comment: Is the error you've shown from before or after you tried installing an older (`3.4.0`) version? If you've received the same error with more than version, what are all the versions you've tried? Is there a chance other things about your Python environment (Python version, etc) have changed since it last worked? Do you know for sure which Python/library versions were used when the model was saved, or roughly when the model was saved? Have you tried an up-to-date version of Gensim?

Comment: It was before installing 3.4.0, it was saved using gensim==3.8.3. I have tried 3.2.0 and 3.3.0. It is the same environment that I was using when it was saved, Python version is the same but installed another package and so now other packages are failing too.

Comment: If it was originally saved using `3.8.3`, generally only `3.8.3` or later will be likely able to load it. Have you tried ensuring `3.8.3` is installed – and reported as the definite version being used by the definite Python interpreter/environment you're executing – to see if the same, or a different, error recurs?